# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard is crashing when trying to export to Oracle

Tags: sql-server-2008, export

I am trying to migrate SQL Server 2008 table records to an Oracle 11g database using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Steps:

1. Select the SQL Database -> Right Mouse click
2. tasks - > export data
3. Choose a data source (keep the default options)
4. Click "Next" button
5. Choose  a Destination: (Oracle Provider for OLE DB)
6. Select the table and click Finish Button

There are millions of records in the table, but after copying a couple of million records, SQL  Server Import and Export Wizard is crashing.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a feature! (Feature: vendor lock-in.)

Comment: Can you please suggest a better way to copy tables from sql server to oracle database

Comment: To the 'answerers', this has nothing to do with zillions of rows. The only way we can reach 'Tasks' is, by right-clicking on the DB name. This POS (which is actually a great tool, and only one that could connect to a remote SS instance via SSL) works first time after install, then crashes everytime after that. None of the answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279586/sql-server-management-studio-closes-immediately-after-startup) worked, except re-install which takes forever, and needs restarts :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Rows per batch or maximum insert commit size if you dealing with millions of transactions.
Not sure if the Wizard has option to specify the Rows per batch or maximum insert commit size.
If not, you need to create a SSIS package to do so.

Comment: The wizard does not showing the "Rows" per batch option.

Comment: You need to create a SSIS package from Visual Studio and specify the sizes. SQL server not able to hold millions of rows and commit at one shot --- Crash :(

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Henry, If you want to deal with million's of record try to create a package instead of using the old import export wizard and set functionality like rows per batch, maximum insert commit size. but you need to be aware of your system capacity to set this options.