# SSMS 18.6 crashes on startup

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Running SSMS 18.6 causes the program to launch, hang, and then crash. There is no error message given, the program simply terminates before any action is taken and nothing is connected.

I've uninstalled and deleted all files for SSMS, Visual Studio, and SQL Complete.
I tried the 18.6 and 18.5.1 versions of SSMS to no avail.

From https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237086/sql-server-management-studio-18-wont-open-only-splash-screen-pops-up/237087#237087 :
I have tried copying the Interop.8.0.dll file from privateassemblies into public. No effect. The line in the config file mentioned here is already commented out in the recent release of SSMS.

From [Sql Server Management Studio closes immediately after startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279586/sql-server-management-studio-closes-immediately-after-startup) :
I have tried renaming or deleting the package file listed here and removed the relevant registry key. This causes SSMS not to open at all and Windows to issue an alert sound. No other effect.

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/9d0e2459-eb74-46e8-a983-05ae2ba18977/ssms-crashes-on-startup?forum=sqltools :
I tried to repair .NET framework. No effect.

I was only able to install and successfully connect on SSMS version 17.9.1

I can provide Event Viewer details if anyone is willing to help me troubleshoot. I have a .NET Runtime error and two application errors- one is event name CLR20r3 and the other is APPCRASH. Happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: So you're saying it's no longer just when you run is as the local administrator, as you said [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63468490/2029983)? Why not just edit your last question?

Comment: @Larnu correct. For brevity. The administrator angle is not really relevant, so I didn't want to confuse anyone. This situation is my first posting interaction with stackexchange, so not sure what the SOP is here.

Comment: If you launch it from a Command Prompt do you get any STDERR output? Sounds like it's missing DLL dependencies somewhere. If you can still find the ancient "depends.exe" Dependency Walker tool from Microsoft and open the main executable with it does it provide any clues about missing static references?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Nope. It just launches and crashes as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't speak to the exact reason it happened, I found a solution. Whatever the issue was, I discovered it was user specific and limited to my machine. Other users were able to access SSMS as normal on my machine as was I on theirs.

I happened to remember that the AppData folder exists and is just hidden, so I used an administrator account to copy that from a working user and rewrite the files in both of mine that were not used in some background process. This allowed me to once again access SSMS both as my regular user and with my elevated administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue (it happened all of a sudden perhaps due to a windows update). I also tried all the other solutions listed above, but the only thing that worked for me was to uninstall and then reinstall version 7.9.1 like the original poster recommended.

In my case I only have 1 user on the computer, so the other user accounts being able to access was not applicable.